# How can I capture SOAP request and response messages in Java?

Tags: java, tomcat, soap, apache-axis

```
SimpleCalculatorStub stub = new SimpleCalculatorStub(null, 
"http://localhost:8080/ControlSOAPMessage/services/SimpleCalculator");

MyAdd reqMyAdd = new MyAdd();
MySub reqMySub = new MySub();
reqMyAdd.setA(4);
reqMyAdd.setB(4);
reqMySub.setA(9);
reqMySub.setB(5);
MyAddResponse resMyAdd = stub.myAdd(reqMyAdd);
MySubResponse resMySub = stub.mySub(reqMySub);
// System.out.println(resMyAdd.get_return()+" :: "+resMySub.get_return());
Integer[] resParams = new Integer[2];
resParams[0]=resMyAdd.get_return();
resParams[1]=resMySub.get_return();
for (int i = 0; i < resParams.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(resParams[i]);
}
```

I want to capture every request and response of SOAP messages (RAW) coming/going to/from client/server in XML format while interacting with Services.

Please guide me with program coding and where I should place that coding. 
I have made this service using Eclipse Axis2 plugins. Dynamic Web Project->Web Services (Java, Axis2, Tomcat 6)

I have attached client side program(simple one)

- Addition and subtraction methods
- Client accepts two arguments in each method
- Add or subtract the numbers and provide results

Please guide me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Apache's TCPMon](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/) or if you use eclipse ee, it is integrated in it. Just go to Window->Show View and find TCP/IP Monitor. These two work as a *proxy*, your client will connect to the TCPMon, and you configure TCPMon to connect to your server.

There are other tools that you can put them between the client and the server so that you can monitor the traffic (like Wireshark).

Comment: I want to do the same work programatically as TCPMon does and want to save these soap messages on some files
But I don't know how to intercept or create handlers for those messages and saved on some files. 
please help me with the coding and where to place that coding